# LibreOffice5 Update

Tags: updates, libreoffice

Now that LibreOffice 5 is out can we expect an update soon?
I am using 4.2.8.2 just now on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and can get the update directly but would prefer the updates via Ubuntu automatic system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [LibreOffice packaging team](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice) provides PPAs for various versions and backports of LibreOffice. You can install the most recent stable branch (currently 6.0) from this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I dual boot to Windoze 10 and installed 5 there to check it out and found it to be very nice but very much slower then 4.*.* and in Calculate there is an issue with seeing content of cells when highlighted so may wait and see how it develops a little more before taking the Plunge.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should know that the version you're running (`4.2.*.*`) is tested for 14.04 LTS version and I would not recommend you to upgrade to next version.

Even if you want to upgrade you can alternatively get it from terminal by doing the following:

1. First add this ppa `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` by typing in terminal:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
   ```
2. Then type

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

You are good to go :)

Comment: `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` only contains branch 5.0.x even though there's a sister PPA with 5.1.x.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I dual boot to Windoze 10 and installed 5 there to check it out and found it to be very nice but very much slower then 4.*.* and in Calculate there is an issue with seeing content of cells when highlighted so may wait and see how it develops a little more before taking the Plunge.